# static margin to right and left side in a div, adjusting to screen resolution

Tags: css

I need to get the fixed margin to the right and left side using a wrapper inside an absolute div (it should work with relative, but I'm limited). Here is the graphics of the desired result using different screen  resolutions:

[image]

what I am currently getting to work is the left "50px width" margin, but the **right "5px width"** seems like **it's not working**.

I've heard that for some things javascript can be helpful, yet I could not find implementations of this kind.

**CSS:**

```
.main_wrap{
width:100%
position:absolute;
}

.div_contener {
position:absolute;
height:400px;
border:1px solid blue;
left:50px;
width:100%
margin-right:5px;
width:100%
}

.div_sub_wrapper {
position:absolute;
width:100%;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="main_wrap">

<div class="div_sub_wrapper">

<div class="div_contener">
<p>sample words</p>
</div>
  </div>
     </div>
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uxNzF/)**

The other thing is that if I use a fixed with size for the `contener` class, it should not get scrolling like it does now with this 100% width.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a `left` and a `right` css. If the `width` is `auto` it will fill the space:

```
.div_container {
    left:50px;
    right:5px;
    width:auto;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uxNzF/1/

Comment: Thanks for replying @nicholas, definetively, auto fills the same. But  when applying right 5px I'm not getting the desired outcome from the graphics. It ofcourse does a margin of 5px, but the border is outside of that margin, and it's getting scrolling too. but thanks for the answer